# Showing pop over from Bar Button in Navigation bar in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uipopover

In Swift, I'm trying to show a popover from a bar button item present in the top right position of navigation bar. Below is my code:

```
func showOptions(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let optionsVC = OptionsViewController(nibName: "OptionsViewController", bundle: nil)
    optionsVC.delegate = self
    optionsVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    optionsVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)

    present(optionsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let popController = optionsVC.popoverPresentationController
    popController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
    popController?.delegate = self
    popController?.barButtonItem = sender
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Its working good in iPad and not in iPhone. I've gone through the documentation and different web pages. Everything seems to be right. What's missing in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem here is you are presenting `OptionsViewController` before setting its popover delegate. So first set its delegate then call present function.

```
let popController = optionsVC.popoverPresentationController
popController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
popController?.delegate = self
popController?.barButtonItem = sender

present(optionsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```